# Proxies in list refusing to rotate-- More concise version

Tags: python, selenium, backend, user-agent, http-proxy

Although all the proxies in the list that I am using are dead, I should at least get "proxy - not working" instead, all I am getting is this weird set of errors.

It seems to get past the enter 'url and # of views', but after that, the errors as shown in the pictures occur. How do i resolve this issue so that it runs or so that I get "proxy - not working" if the proxy is actually dead. I want to resolve this issue before purchasing better proxies. Screenshot of error:  [image: pic1] [image: pic2]

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import random
import re

from fake_useragent import UserAgent

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random



headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
def get_proxies():
    proxyList = []
    file=open('proxylistsm.txt',mode='r')
    for i in file.readlines():
        proxyList.append(i)
    return proxyList



 def search_and_click(i,proxyList,sleep_time,url):
    #change the url to https://httpbin.org/ip that doesnt block anything
    r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', headers=headers, proxies={'http' : f'http://{i}','https': f'https://{i}'}, timeout=5)
    print(r.json(), r.status_code)
    options.add_argument(f"user-agent={userAgent}")
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % i)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    driver.get(url) 
    try:
       
    #-#
    print(driver.title)
    add_to_cart = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Featured--button")
    add_to_cart.click()
    sleep(sleep_time)
    driver.quit()
except:
       

    print(i +' - not working')
    driver.quit()
    i = random.choice(proxyList)
    search_and_click(i,proxyList,sleep_time,url)

def run_Script():
proxyList = get_proxies()
userInput = user_Inputs()
#print(userInput[0], userInput[1])
for view in range(userInput[1]+1):
    sleep_time = random.randint(5,random.randint(8,16))
    proxy = random_proxy(proxyList)
    search_and_click(proxy,proxyList,sleep_time,userInput[0])
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_Script()
```

Comment: I hope you are crawling a large number of sites (not just a single Website) using these proxies...

Comment: Why do you say so? @Brandon

Comment: If you do not own the website, then it will generate a large amount of traffic to that site, which incurs more costs. But I didn't notice initially that you are using a long sleep time, so it's probably OK.

Comment: Ok @Brandon, would you be able to help me with my issue though?